# Why does Date.UTC gives back a string of milliseconds

Tags: javascript

UTC  is of format - 1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00

But why does Date.UTC gives a string representing milliseconds ?

How can I achieve the same in Javascript and what are the browser compatibility cases I need to take care of while doing without external library ( say moment ).

Comment: reading reference is a good start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: On top of that, what you've given as an example - it is not a UTC. UTC time is always at offset 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date.UTC returns the date in the UTC/GMT timezone, as a Unix timestamp.

What you are referring to as UTC format is ISO-8601 format, and you retrieve that with the [toISOString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) method. For example:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
```